# "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

Tags: angular, typeerror, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

Please i am new to Angular and i am following a tutorial by Felipe Coury. in a chapter of the book(writing your first angular 2 web application), He uses ".value" to display the title and the link in which we are to input. for him it worked well but on my system it keeps showing "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined".

this is my code,

---

```
enter code here
app.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Http } from '@angular/http/src/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-registration',
  templateUrl: './registration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registration.component.css']
})
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

  rForm: FormGroup;
  post:any;                     // A property for our submitted form
  password:string = '';
  dob:string='';
  address:string='';
  city:string='';
  name:string = '';
  email:string='';
  titleAlert:string = 'This field is required';

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,private router: Router,private http:HttpClient) {
    this.rForm = fb.group({
      'name': [null, Validators.required],
      'dob': [null, Validators.required],
      'address': [null, Validators.required],
      'city': [null, Validators.required],
      'email': [null,Validators.email],
      'password': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(12)])],

      'validate' : ''
    });
   }
   submit(rForm){   
      if(this.rForm.valid){
        console.log("hiii");

        console.log(rForm.value.name);
        console.log(rForm.value.dob);
        console.log(rForm.value.address);
        console.log(rForm.value.city);
        console.log(rForm.value.email);
        console.log(rForm.value.password);




        const body = JSON.stringify({

           'name':rForm.value.name,
           'dob':rForm.value.dob,
           'address':rForm.value.address,
           'city':rForm.value.city,
           'email':rForm.value.email,
           'password': rForm.value.password,
           'status': 'A'
              });


              const httpOptions = {
                headers: new HttpHeaders({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*' 
                  }
                )
              };

           this.http.post('http://192.168.134.108:8080/registration/',body,httpOptions)
           .subscribe
         (data =>
         {
          alert('Succesfully Added User'); 
          console.log(data);
         }
         ,
         (err)=> console.log('error occurred')
        );

        rForm.reset();


        console.log("hii");
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
      else{

        this.rForm.controls['name'].markAsTouched(),
        this.rForm.controls['password'].markAsTouched(),
        this.rForm.controls['dob'].markAsTouched(),
        this.rForm.controls['address'].markAsTouched(),
        this.rForm.controls['city'].markAsTouched(),
        this.rForm.controls['email'].markAsTouched()    

      }

   }

   reset(){
    console.log("hlo");
    this.rForm.reset();
   }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

---

```
<body>
    <div *ngIf="!name; else forminfo">
        <form [formGroup]="rForm" >
            <div class="form-container">

                <div class="first">                        
                    <div class="form">                
                        <h4>Full Name:</h4>

                            <input type="text" formControlName="name" class="text-control" id="name"  placeholder="Full Name"><br>
                            <small class="alert" *ngIf="!rForm.controls['name'].valid && rForm.controls['name'].touched">{{ titleAlert }}</small>
                            <br>
                        <h4>Date of Birth:</h4>

                            <input type="date" formControlName="dob" class="text-control" id="dob"  placeholder="dd/mm/yy"><br>
                            <small class="alert" *ngIf="!rForm.controls['dob'].valid && rForm.controls['dob'].touched">{{ titleAlert }}</small>
                            <br>
                        <h4>Address:</h4>

                            <input type="text" formControlName="address" class="text-control" id="address"  placeholder="address"><br>
                            <small class="alert" *ngIf="!rForm.controls['address'].valid && rForm.controls['address'].touched">{{ titleAlert }}</small>
                            <br>
                        <h4>city:</h4>

                            <input type="text" formControlName="city" class="text-control" id="city"  placeholder="city"><br>
                            <small class="alert" *ngIf="!rForm.controls['city'].valid && rForm.controls['city'].touched">{{ titleAlert }}</small>
                            <br>
                        <h4>Email:</h4>

                            <input type="text" formControlName="email" class="text-control" id="email"  placeholder="example@gmail.com"><br>
                            <small class="alert" *ngIf="!rForm.controls['email'].valid && rForm.controls['email'].touched">{{ titleAlert }}</small>
                            <br>
                        <h4>Password:</h4>

                            <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="text-control" id="password"  placeholder="password"><br>
                            <small class="alert" *ngIf="!rForm.controls['password'].valid && rForm.controls['password'].touched">Password must be 6 to 12 charecters</small>
                            <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="button-control">
                        <button class="button"   (click)="submit()">
                        submit
                        </button>

                        <button class="button"   (click)="reset()" >
                        reset
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You getting error in console(console.log(rForm.value.name);) ? Well in this case, you need to write "this.rForm.value"